# how to find which action is firing when a page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to take over maintenance of an existing project ASP.NET MVC application. When the main page loads, it is doing a redirect to some other domain and leaving the application. I tried tracing to see where this redirect is coming from, but the issue is that I cannot find which controller action is firing to even cause this to happen. Searching files in solution for the URL string won't work either because there's redirects all over the place. I tried putting a breakpoint in the Index() method of each Controller on the site, but none of them hit. Is there some easier way to find out which code is executing when you load up an ASP.NET MVC site from inside VS2010?

thanks!

Comment: Examine the requested route against the routing table. You can use the Route Debugger to help:  http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx  Or play with Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/Talk

Comment: If you are using chrome, you can check the network tab and see outgoing requests

Comment: Aside from controller action methods, you might also want to see if any module is intercepting the request and handling the redirect